# 2D uniform distribution sample

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am looking for a way to take a random sample of a uniform distribution in 2D square. Is there a single function for this? Or do I have to take the x and y axis separately uniformly distributed each like:

```
x=numpy.random.uniform(0,1,1000)
y=numpy.random.uniform(0,1,1000)
sample=numpy.column_stack((x, y))
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, but [according to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) you can give a shape as a size as an argument to the function. Shouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: That's a great way to do that! There's nothing wrong with using this as the solution.